# Archiving data in SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Need some advice on how best to approach this. Basically we have a few tables in our database along with archive versions of those tables for deleted data (e.g. Booking and Booking_archive). The table structure in both these tables is exactly the same, except for two extra columns in the archive table: DateDeleted and DeletedBy.

I have removed these archive tables, and just added the DateDeleted and DeletedBy columns to the actual table. My plan is to then partition this table so I can separate archived info from non-archived.

Is this the best approach? I just did not like the idea of having two tables just to distinguish between archived and non-archived data.

Any other suggestions/pointers for doing this?

Comment: Doing "partioning" using table names is going to be complicated at some time. If you *can* partition them, go with partitioning. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2005 (maybe upgrading to 2008 r2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of archiving is to improve performance, so I would say it's definitely better to separate the data into another table.  In fact, I would go as far as creating an archive database on a separate server, and keeping the archived data there.  That would yield the biggest performance gains.  Runner-up architecture is a 2nd "archive" database on the same server with exactly duplicated tables.

Even with partitioning, you'll still have table-locking issues and hardware limitations slowing you down.  Separate tables or dbs will eliminate the former, and separate server or one drive per partition could solve the latter.

As for storing the archived date, I don't think I would bother doing that on the production database.  Might as well make that your timestamp on the archive-db tables, so when you insert the record it'll auto-stamp it with the datetime when it was archived.

Comment: I agree about the performance gain, but the archived data in our database is not too bad, maybe around an extra several hundred thousand rows. However for large tables maybe a separate table (or separate database as you suggested) is the way to go...

Comment: If it's "not that bad", then really, why archive it at all? MS-SQL can handle it.  Just upgrade your hardware until you have a need for archiving data.  Why create the extra headaches for yourself?

Comment: Yep for now, I will keep it all in one table then. Until a need arises for separate structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution approach depends on:

1. Number of tables having such archive tables
2. What is arrival rate of data into archive tables ?
3. Do you want to invest in software/hardware of separate server

Based on above - various options could be:

1. Same database, different schema on same server
2. Archive database on same server
3. Archive database on different server

Don't go for partitioning if it's archived data and has no chance of getting back into main tables.
You might also add lifecycle management columns on archived data (retention period or expiry date) so that archive data lifecycle can be also managed effectively.